# How to re-bind to a running service?

Tags: android, service, android-binder

My service is a 3-hour timer that should run in the background until the time is finished (even if the user exits the app).

I have successfully created and bound my service with a fragment.
This enables me to show the timer in real time to the user.

When I exit the app the service continues properly and even sends a notification to the user once the timer is complete (Even if the app is not open)

My problem is this:
When the user closes the app and then re-opens it before the timer is finished, I am unable to retrieve the reference to that running service...

Here is my code to create and bind the service

```
private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection(){
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder 
                                   binder){
        TimerService.TimerBinder binderTime
         = (TimerService.TimerBinder) binder;
        Funx.getInstance().setTimerService(binderTime.getOgBinder());
        bound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName){
        bound = false;
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), TimerService.class);
    Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).bindService(intent, connection, 
    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

 @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    if (bound){
        Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).unbindService(connection);
        bound = false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: you dont need any service - all you need is some database keeping your alarm times and `android.app.AlarmManager` (or [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/) support library)

Comment: Once you unbind from a Bound Service (and it is the last client) it will be call `onDestroy` so you can't rebind.  I assume that by luck the notification works as this is run in a separate `Thread`? By luck Android doesn't kill the App over 3 hours and triggers the notification - only a guess ..

Comment: So maybe it is better to recreate the service and retrieve the time remaining from a database

Comment: By using `WorkManager` (abstraction above other classes like `AlarmManager`) and a database (or even shared preferences) you forgo the need for this current `Service`.

Comment: lol I saw your comment the first time Mark and thanks. Since I've already constructed my app to use services, I am trying to avoid rewriting all that code, even if you solution is simpler and implemented from a higher level. I will notate this as a last resort, but thanks!

Comment: @ParisB.G. What you want isn't how Android works.  It can't be done reliably.  Use JobScheduler/AlarmManager/WorkManager.